# Why don't deleted files and folders go away when deleted?

Tags: windows-7, file-management

I've got a problem with some of my folders on this PC. At one point I had two folders with exactly the same name too. When I try to delete them I get some odd errors like:

> Could not find this item. This item is no longer located in C:/path.
>   Verify the items location and try again.

What is causing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. It's on an external USB drive on a network. I have several files with zero length and no extension, and they appear to have the same name as some folders I had. I can delete them without error (in Windows Explorer or using `DeleteFile()`, which returns success). But when I refresh the directory, there they are again. It's unfortunate you received no assistance on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have found is Windows 7 will not refresh the view correctly or frequently enough. I've gotten the same error before, but mostly on network folders. Now when I delete something, if I still see the folder or item, I will refresh the view by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Some have said resetting the folder views will resolve this;

1. Open Explorer
2. Click Organize
3. Choose `Folder and search options`
4. Select the `View` tab
5. Click <kbd>Reset Folders</kbd> at the top.

Comment: That button is light grey, it won't work. Why is it doing that?

Comment: Do you have full administrative privileges on this PC?

Comment: Yes, yes I do. I don't know whats wrong.

Comment: You could [use the System File Checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833). Or try a repair install of Windows.

Comment: For anyone else with this problem: I had to reinstall Windows 7 in order to fix this issue. I saved my files and data but the OS was not recoverable in the state that it was in. This was some time ago; and it may also have been the result of a bad hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

**Delete these folders using Linux**

Consider this: *C:/path*

Notice the incorrect slash than what Windows uses. Windows cannot delete these folders because the deleting program simply cannot find them when you ask it to delete them. These were probably created by Linux in the first place (this is not necessary).

Simply pop in a Live DVD and you should be able to get rid of these.

Answer (score -1):

It can be deleted  via command prompt.

- Open **cmd** with administrator privileges.
- navigate to the location via **cd** command.
- List directories with **dir** command.
- Find the object to delete and issue **del** command.

Visual guide at [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRSKHv20Usc&t=20).

Comment: I tried this but received a message saying that the directory could not be found when deleting the folder.

Answer (score -1):

I've noticed this on-and-off on my work PC and I just figured it out:

If I delete a file from a folder it goes away immediately, but if I delete a file from a **library that contains the folder**, it remains visible.  And I'll get the "This item is no longer located in..." error if I try to delete it again.

For example:  Deleting a file from `C:\Users\username\Documents` works like you'd expect, but deleting the same file from `Libraries\Documents` will not.